# Как добавить класс к отображаемым блокам div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Имеется код в котором рандомно отображается 4 из 12 блоков div. Подскажите как добавить к блокам ещё класс

```
function shuffle(a) {
  for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
  }
  return a;
}
let s = shuffle(Array.from({length: 12}, (v, k) => k+1))
for(let i = 0; i < 4; i ++) document.getElementById("pic-" + s[i]).style.display = '';
```

забыл дописать html блок которых 12 штук

```
<article id="pic-1" class="product-item catalog-section__box-item">
<a href="/files/" class="product-item__img">
<img class="b-lazy" data-src="/files/img.jpg" src="/files/loading.svg" alt="">      
</a>
<div class="product-item__content">
<a href="" class="product-item__name">12345</a>
</div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для добавления/удаления классов, можно воспользоваться методами **add** и **remove** объекта **classList**.

```
for(let i = 0; i < 12; i ++) {
    if (i < 4) {
      document.getElementById("pic-" + s[i]).classList.add('show');
      document.getElementById("pic-" + s[i]).classList.remove('hide');
    } else {
      document.getElementById("pic-" + s[i]).classList.add('hide');
      document.getElementById("pic-" + s[i]).classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
```

Есть еще метод **toggle**, но в данном случае он не очень подходит.

Работающий пример:

```js
const len = 12; // Сколько div надо создать 
const visible = 4; // Сколько показываем
// Создаем div
const body = document.getElementById('body');

function buildDiv(countDiv) {
  for (let i = 1; i <= countDiv; i++) {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = `pic-${i}`;
    div.innerText = `pic-${i}`;
    body.appendChild(div);
  }
}
buildDiv(len)
// показываем/скрываем
function shuffle(a) {
  for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
  }
  return a;
}

let s = shuffle(Array.from({
  length: len
}, (v, k) => k + 1))
for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  if (i < visible) {
    document.getElementById("pic-" + s[i]).classList.add('show');
    document.getElementById("pic-" + s[i]).classList.remove('hide');
  } else {
    document.getElementById("pic-" + s[i]).classList.add('hide');
    document.getElementById("pic-" + s[i]).classList.remove('show');
  }
}
```

```css
.show {
  display: block;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id='body'></div>
```

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, как отобразить 4 div блока, пример который  я дописал выше

Comment: @Dozent у вас код и преложенный мной обращаются к элементам по ID. Код успешно будет добавлять/удалять нужные классы